# Emulated_Keyboard

Tags: ssh, keyboard

My Problem is that I want to have the raspberry pi connected to the network and a display. I want to interface with the the display connected to the pi over the network. I would only be using terminal so wouldn't need the use of a mouse. So is there some kind of emulated keyboard software over ssh. Maybe ssh into the pi and some how have it display on the main display instead of the terminal I'm using or both?

Comment: This sounds like you either want to use a combination of ssh and tmux, or something like vnc, if you need X11 as well.

Comment: Ha Ha!  Guess what I just wrote?!?  This exact utility!  I call it `fauxcon`, I use uinput to connect to the console kb (soon the mouse too).  Have a look at [fauxcon](https://github.com/lornix/fauxcon)  But I broke it a couple hours ago, working on getting it running again.  A previous commit works quite nicely (danged feature creep!!)

Comment: fauxcon released, fully functional.  github: [fauxcon](https://github.com/lornix/fauxcon)

Answer (score 2):

Old thread, I know.

I've written a utility I call `fauxcon`, which forwards your keyboard (and soon, mouse) to the console of another computer you're ssh'd into.

This allows you to view your RPi's display (for instance) on a TV or monitor, and type as if you were logged into the physical device with a keyboard.

Considering everything in my house is wireless, it's rather neat to sit on the couch with laptop and type away, seeing it happen on the big screen on the RPi.

Feedback welcome,

fauxcon - Github - https://github.com/lornix/fauxcon

Answer (score 1):

your display is connected to your RaspberryPi, right? so you cannot be in another room or in a totally different place, as long as you wish to see the screen.

then, your best bet would be a wireless keyboard (and, probably a mouse combo), connected directly to Pi, you don't need any network or computer, making your setup cheaper and easier to use.

if you don't need wireless, i think any cheap usb keyboard will do the trick as well.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got your question right. If so the answer can be found here

https://superuser.com/questions/67659/linux-share-keyboard-over-network

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.